# Qt4: QTableView mouse button events not caught

Tags: user-interface, qt, qt4

I have a `QTableView` in which I am displaying a custom model. I would like to catch right mouse clicks so that I can open a contextual drop down menu on the underlying table data:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
  QTableView * itsView = new QTableView;
  itsView->installEventFilter(this);
  ... //Add other widgets and display them all
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject * watched, QEvent * event)
{
  if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    printf("MouseButtonPress event!\n");
  else if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    printf("KeyPress event!\n");
}
```

Strangely, I get all of the KeyPress events properly: when I have a cell highlighted and press a key, I get the "*KeyPress event!*" message. However, I only get the "*MouseButtonPress event!*" message when I'm clicking on the very thin border surrounding the entire table.

Comment: Finally, I give up this way. I adopted another better one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442050/qtableview-how-can-i-get-the-data-when-user-click-on-a-particular-cell-using-mo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because the Tableview is this thin border... If you want to access the widget's content, you should instead install your eventFilter on the **Tableview's viewport** !

I therefore propose :

```
QTableView * itsView = new QTableView;
itsView->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
```

Try this, it should fix your problem !

Hope it helps !

Comment: Over six years later and this answer just saved me a bunch of time and annoyance. Thanks!

Comment: @GuyGizmo I'm happy to hear that :) Thanks for stopping by ;)

Comment: That's half worked, mouse-click is triggered, but the receiver is a plain QWidget*, how do I find the clicked cell (index of column and row)?

Comment: Edit for my last comment: `viewport->parentWidget()` can do.

Comment: Strange, the first click is always not reponsed, and the every click always responses to the previous click.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to show a context menu you can use [customContextMenuRequested](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal of the `tableview`; you would need to set context menu policy to `Qt::CustomContextMenu` for this signal to be triggered. Something like this:

```
...
itsView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
QObject::connect(itsView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)),
                 this, SLOT(tableContextPopup(const QPoint &)));
...

void MainWindow::tableContextPopup(const QPoint & pos)
{
    qDebug() << "show popup " << pos;
}
```

Hope this helps, regards.